# Panoramic Background animation in Android

Tags: android, animation

[image: Panoramicbackground]

I have a panoramic background as a sky that i want to move from left to right and then from right to left to simulate a moving clouds animation as a screen background .

This should repeat indefinitely and after goin to the right most then return back to the left most..

I have tried the following:

```
  Animation left = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, com.icare.kids.R.anim.view_transition_out_right);
  left.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
  left.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
  left.setDuration(3000);

  findViewById(id.cloud).startAnimation(left);
```

But this does not seem to work... any solution for that ?

I am currently setting the image to an ImageView as follows:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/cloud"
    android:layout_width="3000dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/topbar"
    android:scaleType="matrix"
    android:src="@drawable/bgpan" />
```

how can i set the image to the screen to start from the left most like this below, so to help in the panoramic animation effect:
[image]

Comment: Why not move the Bitmap instead of the text view? I mean, if you have the background (3000px) loaded in memory, you're really wasting a lot of memory, that is not even visible… you should only cut a piece of the bitmap in each frame of the animation, then get x+OFFSET and so forth, each frame must check bounds to see if you have to start from the left again…

Comment: Stackoverflow has some answers related, look: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17275163/2684

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution that is efficient and fast on all phone ranges was to actually only animate the clouds while keeping the background static.
you can also add some variable to the speed that would add some randomization to the speed of the clouds so you don't get a monotonic looping.

Implementation details and solution was taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17212505/implementing-infinite-scrolling-background-with-forefront-image-in-android/17275163#17275163)

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might be able to try is using a Viewpager object with fake drag, where you continually re-add the background to new views that get generated, while disabling user input.

This will give the illusion of what you are trying to do.

So lets say you have 4 views in your adapter, each view contains just one of the image assets that fills the whole screen, and Viewpager's fake drag pans from View A to View B, draws View C and draws View D, then it fake drags from View B to View C and draws View A again

I'm curious if that would work for you

Comment: mmmm well its a nice idea to do, i think there should be a simple animation trick to do on an ImageView without suing a Viewpager.. but i will look into viewpager if this is my last option thanks for the suggestion

Comment: you are right, there should be @Nader, but I have had a lot of issues with the animation classes